# ext.js rolling back animation parameter

Tags: animation, extjs

I am using Ext.js 5.0, and trying to revert opacity animation as follows:

```
var errorLabel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query( '#errorLabel' )[0];
errorLabel.show();
new Ext.util.DelayedTask( function() {
    errorLabel.animate( {
        duration: 500,
        to:
        {
            opacity: 0
        },
        listeners:
        {
            afteranimate: function()
            {

                // HERE I TRIED LOT'S OF METHODS TO SET BACK THE OPACITY PARAMETER:

                errorLabel.setStyle( 'opacity: 1.0' );
                //errorLabel.setOpacity( 100 );
                // ...
            },
            scope: this
        }
    } );
} ).delay( 3000 );
```

But no success ...

Any clue how can I revert the animation parameters? Is there a general method for doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set style, try using this syntax:

```
errorLabel.setStyle('opacity', '1');
```

Comment: Yup! Thanks a million.. wasted on that too much time ;)